# Show that for a compactly supported function, the sum of L_p norms of partial derivatives is bounded by the L_p norm of sum of partial derivatives.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, fourier-analysis

The following is an exercise in Classical Fourier Analysis by Grafakos:
Prove that for all $1<p<\infty$ there exists a constant $A_{p}>0$ such that for every complex-valued $\mathscr{C}^{2}\left(\mathbf{R}^{2}\right)$ function $f$ with compact support we have the bound
$$
\left\|\partial_{x_{1}} f\right\|_{L^{p}}+\left\|\partial_{x_{2}} f\right\|_{L^{p}} \leq A_{p}\left\|\partial_{x_{1}} f+i \partial_{x_{2}} f\right\|_{L^{p}}.
$$

From the multiplier theory we know the differential operator has multiplier $\xi_i$. But I don't know how to connect it to the above inequality.